# Compiling larger (~6MB) map initializing C++ file with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

I'm trying to compile a C++ file that is some 5.7 MB big. I'm building a 64-bit Linux executable on a 64-bit Linux system. g++ 4.7.2 is unfortunately not cooperative:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

Observing with `top` indicates that the process reaches about 2.2 gigs of memory before that happens. I tried setting `--param gcc-min-expand=0` and also played with `--param gcc-min-heapsize` but that did not resolve the problem. Disabling optimization with `-O0` did not help either.

I also tried compiling with clang, but the results were similar. It segfaulted after also exceeding 2 gigs of memory. I didn't try any extra options with clang because I'm not so familiar with it.

The source file in question consists of C++11-style initialization of a few maps.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> StringToIntMap;
StringToIntMap someData = {{"SOMESTRING", 1}, ..};
```

What I want is preferrably to compile the file with gcc, although if clang can work instead, I can also live with it. It would also be helpful to find out, from someone who knows the internals, just what is happening behind the scenes. If I have a map of 300 000 elements where strings are about 5 bytes long, and an `int` corresponds to each, that's a few megabytes of data, and I can't readily imagine how the initializer blows it up to the point of requiring gigabytes to compile.

And to preempt comments that I should not have such a large source file. I know I can read the data from a data file at runtime, and that's what the program does now, but my use case is such that the program's execution time is the most important factor.

Comment: lol. I'm sure appendix B of the standard gives the compiler permission to start failing a bit earlier than that :/

Comment: Moving this into the source code isn't going to gain much in reality. Right now, it takes M time to load the executable + N time to initialize the maps. With the data pre-loaded you'll end up with an executable that takes (about) M+N time to load. Given demand paging, that'll happen as M time to start executing and N time to page in data at run time. Ultimate difference: a lot more work, but almost no difference in execution speed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Now if this were a `boost::flatmap`, it could be a lot better, but even then, `constexpr` initialization could be better.

Comment: What happens if you create a vector of pairs, then generate the maps dynamically?

Comment: @Mehrdad you waste memory :) You could just use the vector with `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` :/ (Or indeed, boost Flat Map, which does this with a friendlier interface)

Comment: @sehe: There's a huge difference between `flat_map` and `vector`. Flat map checks for duplicates and shifts elements *every time* you insert. I was suggesting he only check for duplicates and sort the elements *once*, at the end, before generating the maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to put implementation defined limits on the amount of supported levels/quantities in many language constructs.

Appendix B lists the *minimum quantities* required for a *conforming compiler*.

From Appendix B, bolding the most relevant ones:

> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or
>   others. The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the
>   minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only guidelines and do
>   not determine compliance.
>
> - Nesting levels of compound statements, iteration control structures, and selection control structures
>     [256].
> - Nesting levels of conditional inclusion [256].
> - Pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combination) modifying a class, arithmetic, or incom-
>     plete type in a declaration [256].
> - Nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full-expression [256].
> - Number of characters in an internal identifier or macro name [1 024].
> - Number of characters in an external identifier [1 024].
> - External identifiers in one translation unit [65 536].
> - Identifiers with block scope declared in one block [1 024].
> - Macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one translation unit [65 536].
> - Parameters in one function definition [256].
> - **Arguments in one function call [256].**
> - Parameters in one macro definition [256].
> - Arguments in one macro invocation [256].
> - Characters in one logical source line [65 536].
> - Characters in a string literal (after concatenation) [65 536].
> - Size of an object [262 144].
> - Nesting levels for #include files [256].
> - Case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch statements) [16 384].
> - Data members in a single class [16 384].
> - Enumeration constants in a single enumeration [4 096].
> - Levels of nested class definitions in a single member-specification [256]
> - Functions registered by atexit() [32].
> - Functions registered by at_quick_exit() [32].
> - Direct and indirect base classes [16 384].
> - Direct base classes for a single class [1 024].
> - Members declared in a single class [4 096].
> - Final overriding virtual functions in a class, accessible or not [16 384].
> - Direct and indirect virtual bases of a class [1 024].
> - Static members of a class [1 024].
> - Friend declarations in a class [4 096].
> - Access control declarations in a class [4 096].
> - *Member initializers in a constructor definition [6 144].*
> - Scope qualifications of one identifier [256].
> - Nested external specifications [1 024].
> - Recursive constexpr function invocations [512].
> - Template arguments in a template declaration [1 024].
> - Recursively nested template instantiations, including substitution during template argument deduction (14.8.2) [1 024].
> - Handlers per try block [256].
> - Throw specifications on a single function declaration [256].
> - Number of placeholders (20.8.9.1.4) [10]

Now, initializer lists are actually just 'constructed' from a number of arguments and apparently GCC doesn't quite support the quantity/volume you provided.

There might be options in the man page to alleviate this:

- `-mlarge-data` (which is the default)
- `-mlarge-text` (also the default)

Comment: This certainly explains why the compiler may fail according to the standard, but doesn't really explain the memory use of over 2 gigs. The initializer gets built out of many arguments, and in this case I guess they are of the form `pair <std::string, int> (key, value)`. How does trying to build a way-too-long list of such arguments manage to use 2 gigabytes of memory?

Comment: @user1264727 I don't know. There's a way to find out: debug the compiler (it's open source). Or, you know, you can change your code to use a different approach.

Comment: That is a question born more out of curiosity regarding the inner workings :) It does now seem clear that using this approach is not worth it even if it could be forced to compile.